# Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release (PM2 in production)

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I have this error message when i run my projet in production with Pm2 :

> src/Entities/Item.ts(4,14): error TS1219: Experimental support for
> decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release.
> Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or
> 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.

in tsconfig.json
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,

in Item.ts

```
@Entity()
export class Items extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column()
  name!: string;
}
```

Can someone help me please ?